# Does Bank Of America Credit Card Report to All Credit Agencies?

Tags: credit-card, credit-report, bank-of-america

I was added on my fathers Bank of America visa credit card about a year ago. Recently getting my credit reports I saw that only one had the card listed (Transunion). The other two (Equifax and Experion) don't have it listed. Does Bank of America report to all three companies? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your case**, maybe there's something in the way BofA reports when you're not the primary account holder (i.e., someone adds you as an authorized user) so that it isn't going to show on your credit report.

Sometimes it can take awhile for accounts to appear on your credit report (up to several months), depending on how and how often the creditors report to the bureaus.

Not every creditor reports to all of the credit agencies, for varying reasons.  It seems odd that BofA wouldn't be reporting to at least both TransUnion *and* Equifax, so this is worth a phone call.

Sometimes when this happens its because the information the creditor is reporting is incorrect and doesn't match up to someone's credit file, so the bureaus don't list it.  A social security number, date of birth, or name doesn't match (or perhaps some other detail), so it gets sidelined and never reported.

In any event, this is worth a quick call to BofA customer service to ask, and maybe they can either fix it if there's a problem or you can simply sign up for your own BofA account and have it reported.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Calling the phone line the woman replied that authorized user accounts should not normally show up on credit reports and do not affect my credit score. This seems strange to me. Is this correct?

Comment: It could very well be true, and it's more of a policy issue for the bank.  The account is based off of the primary account holder's credit score and history, and authorized users are exactly that -- authorized to use the account.  But authorized users don't pay the bill and the bank doesn't hold them accountable for it, which is the danger anyone risks by putting someone on as an authorized user.  That person could max out the card and leave them paying the costs.  Now, if someone else was a *co-signer* on an account, then it would show on both your credit and theirs, so that's different.

Comment: Okay thanks. So I guess I should just let it be then and take the extra info on my Transunion report. Still strange it shows up on one and not on another.

Comment: I understand your point, but it really isn't all that strange or unusual.  There are *many* creditors out there who report to just one or two bureaus, because it costs money and time to do it (meaning they have to format the data to meet each bureau's requirements for uploading bulk data), plus they have to comply with each bureau's requirements for dispute-handling.  They often find it simpler to pick one bureau, since most of the time when your credit is run, a prospective creditor will pull combined reports from all bureaus anyway, so they know about all of your accounts regardless.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Guess my view of society is just to idealized haha. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're certainly welcome.  Glad to help!

Comment: As an update that account now suddenly is showing up on Equifax...strange...who knows if it was that call or just a strange coincidence, but I'm definitely not complaining